# Excel cell html bold tags to bold font

Tags: excel, vb.net

I need to replace in a Excel cell string, all html bold tagged substrings with bold font and remove the tags. I guess I need to loop through the string somehow, at the same time removing tags and setting font like this:

```
xlWorksheet.Cells(1, 2).characters(a, b).font.bold = True
```

This should be done in Windows Forms, vb.net or c#, not VBA.
I know there's a way using Internet Explorer, but I'd rather not use that.
Any leads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Did it myself. This only works with bold tags.

```
xlWs.Cells(1, 2).value = StripTags("this <b>should</b> be <b>bold</b>")
Dim toBold As String = "this <b>should</b> be <b>bold</b>"
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim loopcount As Integer = 0
While i > -1
    Dim startTag As Integer = toBold.IndexOf("<b>", i)
    If startTag = -1 Then Exit While
    Dim endTag As Integer = toBold.IndexOf("</b>", i)
    toBold.Remove(startTag, 3)
    toBold.Remove(endTag, 4)
    xlWs.Cells(1, 2).characters(startTag + 1 - (loopcount * 7), endTag - startTag - 3).font.bold = True
    loopcount += 1
    i = endTag + 1
End While


Function StripTags(ByVal html As String) As String
        Return Regex.Replace(html, "<.*?>", "")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways that you can accomplish what you want to do. Here is a good sample of how to accomplish what you want to do.

http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_update_data_oledb.htm

```
Imports System.Data
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim myCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim sql As String

        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection _
        ("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + _
        "'c:\testfile.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")

        MyConnection.Open()
        myCommand.Connection = MyConnection
        ' This would be where you would find the HTMl or strings that you are trying to change. 
        sql = "Update [Sheet1$] set name = 'New Name' where id=1"


        myCommand.CommandText = sql
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MyConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    MsgBox("Updated ")
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: How would I set the text in t-sql so that its bold in Excel?